# Rails 6 API What are good practices for sending and serializing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, request

I have problem and I don't know how to solve it in a correct way. In my front-end app I have select which shows all products, so I need to send request to my Rails API. Controller has method index that sends all products, but with many different attributes and associations. I don't think so it's a good idea to send request to this method, because in `<select>` I need only product name and id. Example:

`ProductController.rb`

```
 def index
   render json: @products, include: 'categories, user.company'
 end
```

`ProductSerializer.rb`

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :desc, :weight, :amount, ...

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :categories
end
```

As u can see `ProductSerializer` send many things and it is expected but in a different view in FE app. In another page I need only id and name attributes to `<select>`. I know that I can create new `Serializer` and add `if` like this:

```
  def index
    render json: @product, each_serializer: ProductSelectSerializer and return if pramas[:select]
    render json: @products, include: 'categories, user.company'
  end
```

But I'm not sure is a good idea to create new `Serializer` only for one request, because in bigger application can be many situations like this. This `if` in index method dose not looks good too in my opinion, so maybe I should create new method for this request, but it's worth for one small request? Are there any good practices that can help to properly resolve such situations?

Comment: In a JSON API I wouldn't only support one response format per resource (and perhaps user type). If you really want to return different attributes depending on the client's need then I would suggest looking into adding a GraphQL API.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't hear about GraphQL API, but i will check it. Then what would you do in presented situation if you had to use JSON API?

Comment: Why do you want to have different formats returned? Do you expect a performance benefit? Or do you need to exclude sensitive value from certain users?

Comment: For both reasons, in fact. Sometimes json can be so big that it doesn't make sense to send it in this form if the client only needs id and name. There are also situations where some user roles should not see several keys in json and that also needs to be resolved in some way. I was using `attribute :company, if: :seller?`, but when we have many attributes and roles it doesn't looks good ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to try [blueprinter](https://github.com/procore/blueprinter). It a gem that help you to serializing your data and this gem is suitable with your needs.

To create the Blueprinter's serializer you can run this command in your terminal :

```
rails g blueprinter:blueprint Product
```

After You create the searializer, you may define different outputs by utilizing views:

```
class ProductBlueprint < Blueprinter::Base
  identifier :id

  view :normal do
    field :product_name
  end

  view :extended do
    fields :product_name, :product_price
    association :user, blueprint: UserBlueprint
    association :categories, blueprint: CategoryBlueprint 
    # this will take the association from your product's model and make sure you have created the CategoryBlueprint and UserBlueprint
  end
end
```

After you define the view, now you can use the view in your controller. In your index action, you can call it with this syntax.

```
  def index
    render json: ProductBlueprint.render_as_hash(@product, view: :normal) and return if params[:select]
    render json: ProductBlueprint.render_as_hash(@products, view: :extended)
  end
```

Comment: Hmm..., interesting. Can u create there custom methods for every attribute and association?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, first you can create your custom method in your model’s class. After that you can call it in the blueprint serializer’s view with the same way as you call the attribute